# How to increment/intake multiple events with different inputs using ActionListener

Tags: java, events, increment

I am trying to get an input of a details of multiple events and print them in the TextArea. However, each event I put in resets every time I put in a new input, but I want to keep my initial event and then add onto it, if that makes sense. How can I fix my code to do that? Do I need a loop?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*; 

public class Interface {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WidgetViewer wv = new WidgetViewer();
        
        JLabel eventName = new JLabel("Event Name");
        wv.add(eventName, 10, 30, 300, 20);
        
        JTextField name = new JTextField();
        wv.add(name, 10, 50, 300, 20);
        
        JLabel eventVenue = new JLabel("Event Venue");
        wv.add(eventVenue, 10, 70, 300, 20);
        
        JTextField venue = new JTextField();
        wv.add(venue, 10, 90, 300, 20);
        \\ And similar code for the rest of the inputs
        
        JButton create = new JButton("Create an Event");
        wv.add(create, 10, 320, 300, 20);
        
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea("");
        wv.add(text, 10, 460, 900, 20);
        
        create.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                
                String eventName = name.getText();
                String eventVenue = venue.getText();
                int venueCapacity = Integer.parseInt(capacity.getText());
                String eventDate = date.getText();
                int ticketsSold = Integer.parseInt(sold.getText());
                int ticketPrice = Integer.parseInt(price.getText());
                int overhead = Integer.parseInt(costs.getText());
                Event event1 = new Event(eventName, eventVenue, venueCapacity, eventDate, ticketsSold, ticketPrice, overhead);
                
                text.setText("Event " + event1.getEventName() + ", Venue: " + event1.getEventVenue() + ", Date: " + 
                event1.getDate() + ", Tickets Sold: " + event1.getTicketsSold() + ", Ticket Price: " + 
                event1.getTicketPrice() + ", Overhead: " + event1.getOverhead() + ", Venue Capacity: " + event1.getVenueCapacity() + ", Profit: " + event1.getProfit() +
                        ", Break Even Point = " + event1.getBreakEvenPoint());
                
                name.setText("");
                venue.setText("");
                capacity.setText("");
                date.setText("");
                sold.setText("");
                price.setText("");
                costs.setText("");
                
            }
        });   

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok a suggestion - refactor some of the code:

First create a new private variable called currentEvent - keep the Data there.

```
public class Interface()
{
//the variables are static because you do everything in the main method
//this is very un-advisable, you should either create a new object of Interface (not a good name as for a class as interface is a java concept) and use it or as suggested below refactor the whole structure
private static Event currentEvent ;//in case of single event
private static List<Event> myEvents;//in case of multiple events
//the rest of the code you wrote goes here
}
```

in your Event class add a method to print the event.

```
public String printMe()
{
return "Event " + event1.getEventName() + "\n"+ 
"Venue: " + event1.getEventVenue() + "\n"+
"Date: " + event1.getDate() + "\n"+
"Tickets Sold: " + event1.getTicketsSold() + "\n"
"Ticket Price: " + event1.getTicketPrice() + "\n"+
"Overhead: " + event1.getOverhead() + "\n"+
"Venue Capacity: " + event1.getVenueCapacity() + "\n"+ 
"Profit: " + event1.getProfit() +"\n"+ 
"Break Even Point = " + event1.getBreakEvenPoint();

}
```

now instead of the code you wrote in the action listener you just need to use
`text.setText(event1.printme());`

as for The request if i understand  -
if you  want to add data to the same event
add methods that will add to the data

the Event class will look something like -

```
public void addToName(String name)
{
    this.name=this.name+"name"
}
```

etc

if you want to have MULTIPLE events - have a List variable instead of one event variable and in the action listener
just take in the new data and add as a new event

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            
            String eventName = name.getText();
            String eventVenue = venue.getText();
            int venueCapacity = Integer.parseInt(capacity.getText());
            String eventDate = date.getText();
            int ticketsSold = Integer.parseInt(sold.getText());
            int ticketPrice = Integer.parseInt(price.getText());
            int overhead = Integer.parseInt(costs.getText());
            Event event1 = new Event(eventName, eventVenue, venueCapacity, eventDate, ticketsSold, ticketPrice, overhead);
            
            //this is the addition to the list    
            myEvents.add(event1);               
            //print them all
            String eventsText="";
            myEvents.forEeach((event)->{eventsText=eventsText+event.printme()+"\n";});
            //add to textBox
            text.setText(eventsText)
            name.setText("");
            venue.setText("");
            capacity.setText("");
            date.setText("");
            sold.setText("");
            price.setText("");
            costs.setText("");
            
        }
    });
```

last word - think about taking everything out of the main method, and instead of a text area i would have used JLabel (show the details only and wont allow for edits where they arent supposed to go).

Suggestion to correct code design:
in general learn MVC -

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm

in regard to your question
1)build a class to handle the display - this will handle building a Jpanel
the panel will contain what you
2)build a main class - it will instantiate a frame and set the panel to be the panel from your display class
3)build a controller class that will implement the Action Listener and handle mouse clicks.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this! I have some questions - where do I put the private variable curentEvent and why do I add it if you did not use it in the actionPerformed? Also, my instructor doesn't allow us to use concepts we did not learn, and I do not recognize `myEvents.forEeach((event)->{eventsText=eventsText+event.printme()+"\n";});`. Is there a way to do the same without using this method?

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate?

Comment: i suggested 2 things in order to cover 2 scenarios:
1.you want to add something to the same event -in which case you need to save one event and add to it
2. you want to save multiple events and print them in which case you save a list and add new events to it

either way the data should be stored in a variable at the class level (after the class declaration)

because you do everything inside main class the variables should be static

i will say now and i cant stress this enough - your code at the moment is horribly designed. - added further suggestions inside the answer

Comment: I understand. I've only been coding for 2 months so I'm not good. I will try my best to make it better. I have other classes where I moved some methods to so it's a little cleaner. My questions from my first comment still stand, but I will try to figure it out myself. My teacher does not allow for us to use techniques we did not learn. Thank you for your help

Comment: myEvents.forEeach((event)->{eventsText=eventsText+event.printme()+"\n";}); 
can be easily refactored to : 
for(int i =0;i<myEvents.size();i++)
{
eventsText=eventsText+myEvents.get(i).printme()+"\n";
}